# How to add UICollectionView in UICollectionView (programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Watching a youtube, I'm studying.
I want to change parts.
ImageView want to use instead UICollectionView.
So I want to scroll the image horizontally.
I would like to know how to add UICollectionView.
How can I ...?
[image]

code: https://github.com/purelyswift/facebook_feed_dynamic_cell_content

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image, it looks more like a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableView`. See [this article](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/)